# Voice Recorder "Phone Storage"

Tags: audio, file-transfer, voice-recording

Apparently on my latest HTC phone, the voice recorder default storage setting is set to "Phone Storage" as opposed to "SD Card".  I just switched the setting to "SD Card".  From my Win 7 PC, I can view the new *.amr files now saved to the SDCard in \My Documents\My Recordings.

I want to find and transfer previous 150 recordings stored on "Phone Storage" ultimately to my PC.  If I need to go to SDCard first, that's fine, but how?

Comment: Did you try removing your sd card and connecting the device to a computer?

Comment: I have an otter case, somewhat of a pain to take apart. Seems like I could use FileExplorer or something to transfer files to SDCard?  Do you need "Root" or something to view phone disk itself?

Comment: If it allows you to, of course!

Comment: Still note sure what you are saying I should try now.  I tried file explorer, and couldn't see the drive either.  Why would removing the sd card help... I'm still stuck...

Comment: When I look in ES File Explorer, I see Voice0001.amr through Voice0152.amr. When I plug phone into Win7, my H drive, same folder shows Voice0153.amr through Voice0160.amr.  I don't understand why the files below 153 show only on phone.  For now, I think I'm going to share them to DropBox, but I'd like to figure how to to get to them via USB share-drive connection.

Comment: Then Simply use the share function to bluetooth the files to your PC or copy/move them to another folder in your SD card